# C# Winforms difference between DoubleClick event and MouseDoubleClick event

Tags: c#, winforms

Quick question here:
As the title says, what's the difference between the two events?

As far as I can tell, `MouseDoubleClick` is inherited from `Control`, while `DoubleClick` is inherited from `Component`, but is there any functional difference between the two?

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedoubleclick%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> DoubleClick events are logically higher-level events of a control. They may be raised by other user actions, such as shortcut key combinations.

Comment: prolly, this is the only answer here, or otherwise the only good answer. short and to the point.

Answer (score 12):

I believe the key difference between these two is the event handler where the "DoubleClick" event will include a simple EventArgs object while the "MouseDoubleClick" will include a MouseEventArgs which will include the position of the mouse among other things.

So basically if you need to know where the click occurred on the control, I would favor "MouseDoubleClick" over "DoubleClick".

**DoubleClick**

```
private void DoubleClick_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

**MouseDoubleClick**

```
private void MouseDoubleClick_Event(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
```

Comment: This is not exactly the answer I was looking for, but I really liked the fact that you are highlighting the most important functional difference

Answer (score 6):

As you can see here: [Control.MouseDoubleClick Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedoubleclick.aspx)

> The following series of events is raised by the control when such a
>   user action takes place:
>
> MouseDown event.
>
> Click event.
>
> MouseClick event.
>
> MouseUp event.
>
> MouseDown event.
>
> DoubleClick event.
>
> MouseDoubleClick event.
>
> MouseUp event.

so there is a difference between the two as the MouseDoubleClick implies all these events to get triggered.

Comment: It seems the DoubleClick also fires these events. What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

explain how these two pages and the differences between the two events

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doubleclick.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedoubleclick.aspx

A double-click is determined by the mouse settings of the user's operating system.

The MouseDoubleClick event occurs when the user depresses a mouse button twice in quick succession when the cursor is over the control.

Regards.

Comment: According to the documentation you provided, both have an interval that is determined by the Operating systems mouse settings.

MouseDoubleClick: "The time interval that separates two single clicks from a double-click is determined by the mouse settings of the user's operating system."

DoubleClick: "A double-click is determined by the mouse settings of the user's operating system."

So the difference stated here is not a difference at all, and is actually the same for both.